# Many to Many relationship Get by id is not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I tried to create a user & pet model in Many to Many relationship using mongoDB and sailsJS, db creation and loading the data's are just fine i checked in mongoDB for dbs and collection it exists. when i try to get the user list and pet list its showing me the contents but when i try to GET a single pet by its iD under user by his iD i'm not getting result

It shows "Response does not contain any data."

I tried to get PET like this 
"http://localhost:1337/user/54ffd28e9d9ee93c166c7500/pets/54ffd28e9d9ee93c166c7503"

I also tried to display the pet by its name instead of iD its also not working

my sails version is 0.11.0..
my OS is Win7 64 bit

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your API? Especially for the route that you are trying to access.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A9hEHKbxSqIMqyOlkAe3LfO6S5hLL6pG60wUAW8GlTU/edit

Comment: Could you please update your post with the source code so that it is readable? It's tiring to read it and format it in the document format that you provided.

Comment: @VladZ. i found the solution in git hub.. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2658 at this location... now its working

Answer (score 0):

here's a maybe useful thing to know, when requesting by id while using mongoDB.

to get some document inside of a collection, passing the id through an URL, it is useful to use the `const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')`.

you can for instance do as following:

```
// VS code might or might not write this for you
// but if you VIM, you have to write yourself

const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')

fastify.get('/something/:id', async function (req, reply) {
    const db = await this.mongo.db;
    await db.collection('YourCollection', callbackFunc);

    function callbackFunc(err, col) {
      if (err) reply.send(err)

      col.findOne({ "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.id) }, (err, result) => 
      {
        console.log(result)
      })
    }
  })
```

Let me know if it helps, best wishes